# Filtering date after max date SQL

Tags: sql-server, maxdate

I have a table with values en date/timstamps. This table is dbo.meterdata.value. The output that i want to see is as followed: The latest date/timestamp (Max) but only the ones where te latest date/timestamp is last week. My Query is:

```
SELECT dbo.meter.DataImportCode
    ,dbo.meter.NAME
    ,dbo.company.NAME
    ,dbo.meter.MeterNumber
    ,MAX(dbo.meterdata.RoundedTimeStamp) AS 'laatste datum'
    ,dbo.MeterOperator.Description
    ,dbo.meter.CumulativeReadings
FROM dbo.meter
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.MeterData ON dbo.meter.MeterID = dbo.meterdata.MeterID
JOIN DBO.Site ON dbo.meter.SiteID = dbo.site.SiteID
JOIN DBO.Company ON dbo.site.CompanyID = dbo.company.CompanyID
JOIN DBO.MeterOperator ON dbo.meter.MeterOperatorID = dbo.MeterOperator.MeterOperatorID
    --WHERE (select (dbo.meterdata.roundedtimestamp) from dbo.MeterData) < DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() )
    AND dbo.meterdata.RoundedTimeStamp IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY dbo.meter.DataImportCode
    ,dbo.company.NAME
    ,dbo.meter.NAME
    ,dbo.meter.MeterNumber
    ,dbo.MeterOperator.Description
    ,dbo.meter.CumulativeReadings
```

Example of the unfilterd result:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LynLE.png)

Thank you for help and support

Comment: Can you please provide us sample data and desired output

Comment: 'Last week' can be interpreted in multiple ways.  Last Sunday to this Sunday?  Exactly 7 days ago?  `DateADD(DD, -7, GETDATE())` is probably giving the wrong answer.  If you are working with datetime, it is definitely giving the wrong answer because it takes into account the time from today and applying it to 7 days ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Time today - 7 days is ok! It's for a data complete check sample data of the not filtered data:

'laatste datum         Name Description
2-4-2018 00:45 Warmte Ebatech
2-4-2018 00:45 Warmte Ebatech
26-3-2018 23:00 Warmte Episensor
6-4-2017 21:15 Gebouw 5 warmte Episensor
2-4-2018 15:00 Gebouw 6 warmte Episensor
25-10-2017 15:00 Gebouw 26 HL-1 Episensor
25-10-2017 15:00 Gebouw 26 HK-2 Episensor
6-4-2017 21:15 Gebouw 21 warmte Episensor
6-4-2017 21:15 Gebouw 21 koude Episensor'

So it's about filtering not de actual dates

Comment: I have the solutions, thanx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select dbo.meter.DataImportCode, dbo.meter.Name, dbo.company.Name, dbo.meter.MeterNumber,MAX(dbo.meterdata.RoundedTimeStamp) AS 'laatste datum', dbo.MeterOperator.Description, dbo.meter.CumulativeReadings
from dbo.meter
LEFT OUTER JOIN DBO.MeterData ON dbo.meter.MeterID = dbo.meterdata.MeterID
JOIN DBO.Site on dbo.meter.SiteID = dbo.site.SiteID
JOIN DBO.Company on dbo.site.CompanyID = dbo.company.CompanyID
JOIN DBO.MeterOperator on dbo.meter.MeterOperatorID = dbo.MeterOperator.MeterOperatorID
--WHERE (select (dbo.meterdata.roundedtimestamp) from dbo.MeterData) < DateAdd(DD,-7,GETDATE() )
--AND dbo.meterdata.RoundedTimeStamp is not null
GROUP BY dbo.meter.DataImportCode, dbo.company.name, dbo.meter.Name, dbo.meter.MeterNumber, dbo.MeterOperator.Description, dbo.meter.CumulativeReadings
HAVING [laatste datum] < DateAdd(day,-7,GETDATE())
```

If I understood you right, what you want to do is filter out the data **after** it has been grouped. This is done using the `HAVING` clause of the `SELECT` statement, as the above query depicts.

Comment: Thank you MK_

I think this could work i only now get: Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  170641680826368' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. etc.

I don't have the rights to check the size of the filegroup so i think i have to simplfy the Query so there are less records. The Group by on dbo.meterdata.RoundedTimeStamp is the cause i think there are a lot of values +- 4000 meters with values for every 15 minutes.

Comment: I have the solutions adding max to the having and not using group by, thanx for the help.

Comment: I'm glad if it's the solution - what you've been looking for. I suggest you mark it as an answer if it's solved now so that it doesn't seem like it's unanswered.